# Again, ObservableCollection doesnt Update item

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Thats my first project using MVVM , MVVM light.
I have a listbox, that gets refreshed from the PersonList Observable collection, adding and removing refresh it normal. the problem is when editing an item.

I looked for all the solutions for this problem, nothing worked, which make me think that I missed something.

so here is the code :

```
 public class AdminViewModel : ApplicationPartBaseViewModel
{
   private ObservableCollection<Person> personList;

   public AdminViewModel()
    {

       this.context = new Entities();
       this.SavePersonCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.SavePerson ());


       this.PersonList = new ObservableCollection<Peson>(context.Person.OrderBy(o => o.PersonName).ToList());


     }

      public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList
    {
        get
        {
             return personList;
        }

        set
        {
            this.personList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PersonList");
        }
    }


     private void SavePerson()
    {
      //Add and update code here
       this.context.SaveChanges();
       RaisePropertyChanged("PersonList");



    }


}
```

Person Class is Autogenerated template from the DataModel edmx

```
 //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public partial class Person 
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public virtual int PersonId
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual string PersonName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual Nullable<int> PersonAge
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Humans> Humans
    {
        get
        {
            if (_human == null)
            {
                var newCollection = new FixupCollection<Human>();
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupHuman;
                _human = newCollection;
            }
            return _human;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_human, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _human as FixupCollection<Human>;
                if (previousValue != null)
                {
                    previousValue.CollectionChanged -= FixupHuman;
                }
                _human = value;
                var newValue = value as FixupCollection<Human>;
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                    newValue.CollectionChanged += FixupAssets;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private ICollection<Human> _human;

    #endregion
    #region Association Fixup

    private void FixupHuman(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Human item in e.NewItems)
            {
                if (!item.Person.Contains(this))
                {
                    item.Person.Add(this);
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Human item in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (item.Person.Contains(this))
                {
                    item.Person.Remove(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I thought that MVVM light update the item when I call RaisePropertyChanged. 
I am so confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: items within an `ObservableCollection<T>` have to implement INPC themselves for your "editing" changes to propagate to the UI.

Comment: when I try to implement it , it says its already implemented in the mvvm light. and I should use override or new keywords.

Comment: please post the Person class code

Comment: Your `Person` class with mvvm light should look like `public class Person : ObservableObject {...}` and you should call `RaisePropertyChanged(...)` on it's properties. This is not to be done  in the `AdminViewModel` class. With this "implementation" now if you modify an object of `Person` in `AdminViewModel`, you'll see the changes get reflected in your View

Comment: Don't raise the PersonList if the reference isn't changed. The whole reason of INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged is to tell WPF exactly what has changed. The first is for property changes, the second for collection changes like add, remove etc. And of course the elements in the observable list again need to utilize INotifyPropertyChanged which has nothing to do with the collection being obserable, that is only to notify about modifying the collection itself.

Comment: I found out (I joined in the middle of the project) that Person Class is a template autogenerated from the Datamodel. I will post the code.

Comment: Viv and Dowwhilefor , you are lighting my way, I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option is try to get your auto-generated class to implement INPC if you can. Have a look at [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/fody/propertychanged)

If that's not possible, since it does have it's properties as "virtual", we can over-ride them in a derived class such as

```
public class ObservablePerson : Person, INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public override int PersonId {
    get {
      return base.PersonId;
    }
    set {
      base.PersonId = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public override string PersonName {
    get {
      return base.PersonName;
    }
    set {
      base.PersonName = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public override int? PersonAge {
    get {
      return base.PersonAge;
    }
    set {
      base.PersonAge = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Now in your `AdminViewModel` work with objects of type `ObservablePerson` than `Person`

Comment: Luckly this MVVM light implement INPC for all classes, so I made first option (without the need of Fody). Thank you very very much :)